# Vim keeps defaulting to soft-tabs when working with .haml files

Tags: vim, tabs, haml

For some reason, Vim keeps using soft-tabs (tabs as spaces) everytime I'm working on Haml files. I prefer regular tabs and have the following in my vimrc:

```
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Which seems to work great for every file type except for Haml. When editing Haml files Vim uses two spaces rather than a tab, any suggestions as to how this can be reverted back to my default settings (ie. regular tabs)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was because the indent script for haml sets expandtab for you automatically when VIM has detected the current file is in haml format.  The script is located at `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/haml.vim`.  It contains:

```
setlocal autoindent sw=2 et
```

To disable that, you can put this line in your `~/.vimrc` to clear the expandtab setting again:

```
au! FileType haml set noet
```

Comment: For some reason adding that to my vimrc still didn't fix it, but I ended up just commenting out the line that was causing the issue and all is good. Thank you!

Comment: You have to put it at the end of the file,  but surely after the line that says "syntax on"